# Unable to create javax script engine for javascript - when using ant command (MAC OS)

Tags: java, ant

I am trying to run the `ant refresh_test_db` command in my project directory in the terminal (Mac OS).
I end up with the following error:

```
[echo] billing.dir has been set to ../billing
Java 15 has removed Nashorn, you must provide an engine for running JavaScript yourself. GraalVM JavaScript currently is the preferred option.

BUILD FAILED
/Users/ygupta/database/build.xml:20: Unable to create javax script engine for javascript
```

I know this error usually pops up when we are using Java 15 or higher (checked other answers here). But when I check my Java version:

```
ygupta@ygupta-macOS ~ % java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_292"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_292-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.292-b10, mixed mode)
```

It's Java 8 only. I am new to this, can someone please help me on this.

Comment: Please show the actual command in the terminal, like you did with `java -version`

Comment: Also the output of the following please: `ant -diagnostics | grep '^java\.home'`

Comment: Even I have a similar problem